# How to use apple ima4 file in android?

Tags: android, ios, ima4

I have iOS code and folder contains .ima files for sound, it is game that using `openAL` in playing sound but I don't have experience in iOS, I want to use these .ima files in android how can I use them or even convert them to mp3 and use them?

Comment: yes , it is in folder -->ipob\__MACOSX\ipob\Resources\ima\sfx , and it is used in sound.c in the original ios code , there is method called to decode IMA ADPCM.

Comment: see this link for decode ima4 http://www.wooji-juice.com/blog/iphone-openal-ima4-adpcm.html

Comment: i see link said that "OpenAL-Soft for Android supports IMA4/ADPCM playback by decoding to PCM on demand in the BufferNeeded callback. We need to do the same on iOS as OpenAL does not support IMA4/ADPCM playback" , So Do i have to just use the library to run IMA4 ?

Comment: to be perfectly honest apple say there's no known way to convert them to mp3 you'd be better off creating your own sounds

Comment: you are right , i was trying to search for any tool makes me listen to these sound and found nothing , but what about using the same files with cross platform audio library?

Comment: check out http://www.fmod.org/download/ it supports ios and android